# Tax price detail

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

In Craft Commerce, when adding a tax rate to a type of product and selecting "this tax is already included in the entered price of all products", I cannot see the tax details for an order.

When it is not selected, the `cart.totalTax` contains the amount of tax due. Once it is selected, that variable always shows zero

Is it possible to include that tax by default, but still see the tax details for the order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution, everything can be found in the variable `cart.adjustments`